# How to Authenticate on SharePoint On Prem with Azure Proxy AD and ADAL?

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to call a Rest Web Service Hosted on SharePoint 2013 server published with Azure Proxy AD (as describe here :[Kirk Evans Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/04/13/azure-ad-application-proxy-and-sharepoint-2013.aspx).
I'm using Adal to Auth on the Azure AD tenant:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false);
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() };
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var result = authContext.AcquireToken("https:/AzureADAppUrl", "ID Apps",new UserCredential("login@domain.com","pass@word"));
```

This get me an access Token, but even If i use this token in the **Bearer** Authorization Header or in a **AzureAppProxyAccessCookie** cookie. I get a 302 redirection response when querying the WCF web service: the Auth is not recognized...
How can I authenticate on an Azure AD Proxy enabled Sharepoint server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application proxy currently only supports interactive authentication, so you can't publish an API using the service.

You are not the first to ask this question, so we are investigating how to enable this in the future.

Disclaimer: I work in the App Proxy team ☺

Comment: Has this now changed?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: As of May 2019, is this still the case ? If we take AADL out of the picture, are we still able to authenticate from outside the azure ad proxy ?